# Регулярные выражения "Правильность ввода имени"

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражение должно проверять ввод имени по следующему правилу:

1. Каждое слово должно быть с большой буквы
2. Может быть 2 или 3 слова
3. Между первым и вторым словом, если их 3, может быть не пробел, а дефис.

При соблюдении этих 3-х правил ввод будет считаться корректным.

Примеры:

> False: Nikolas
>   True: Nikolas Gloom
>   False: Nikolas gloom
>   True: Nikolas-Sebastian Gloom
>   False: Nikolas-Gloom

Сделал пока так:

```
re.match(r'([A-Z]([a-z]*))+', name)
```

Но работает совсем криво. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Занимаетесь ерундой. Самое простое: `Noël Cannat`, `Moses N. Kiggundu`; посложнее: `Juan José Garcìa-Noblejas Liniers`, `Ovidio Saraiva de Carvalho e Silva`, Вашим правилам удовлетворять не будут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.match(r'[A-Z][a-z]*(?:(?: +|-)[A-Z][a-z]*)? +[A-Z][a-z]*$', name)
```

`[A-Z][a-z]*` - заглавная буква, за ней 0 или более маленьких

`( +|-)` - несколько пробелов ИЛИ тире

`(...)?` - вопрос после скобок означает, что этой части может не быть

`?:` в начале скобки означает, что она не будет запомнена

`$` - означает, что идем до конца строки